# Express 4: Handle every and all errors

Tags: node.js, express

While coding my app, I sometimes had a little mishap when typing my URLs in the browser, and thus sometimes got the error message:

```
Cannot GET /some/route
```

Which was true, since the route may was not defined.

But since this app is planned to enter production, I kinda don't want to use this flat message as my "error page".

Looking into the Express 4 docs, they tell me to `.use()` a middleware with 4 arguments. I did that. But I'd still get this issue...

Turns out that this message comes from the `finalhandler` module and my bet is, that this middleware comes before my error-catching, 4-argument middleware.

Here is a basic express app that I threw together while trying to find a solution:

```
var app = require("express")();
app.use("/yo", function(req, res, next){
    res.send("Yo!");
});
app.use(function(error, req, res, next){
    res.send("An error: "+error);
    console.log(error);
});
app.listen(10000);
```

Accessing `/yo` works. But, `/` or `/derp` yields the `Cannot GET` message instead of my little middleware.

So, how is this done correctly, now?

Comment: Are you looking for a fallback route for all undefined routes?

Comment: ThomasBormans: Yeah, something that'll let me handle the "Cannot X" cases. It seems that @mscdex 's solution is the only one I have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error middleware is only for actual errors, such as a middleware or route handler throwing an exception or passing an error to `next()`.

If you want to provide a route handler for requests that do not match any existing routes, then just add a middleware after all of your app's routes/middleware like:

```
var app = require("express")();
app.use("/yo", function(req, res, next){
  res.send("Yo!");
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Could not route your request!');
});
app.use(function(error, req, res, next){
  res.send("An error: "+error);
  console.log(error);
});
app.listen(10000);
```

Comment: Although it'd be cleaner if Express had "missing page/route" handles, this is probably all I can get. Thanks! :)